# $\rm NaI$ detector calibration with $\rm Cs$-137 and $\rm Co$-60 using Genie-2000 software

Tags: experimental-physics, nuclear-physics, radiation, nuclear-engineering

I have tried to calibrate the **NaI** detector with the **NIM** set, **Cs-137**, **Co-60** radioactive sources and **Genie 2000 software**.
I used Cs-137 first and corrected the channel energy then used the Co-60, only **one peak** shows up, as if all three peaks (two for Co-60 and one for Cs-137) are at the same channel and same energy! I thought I would have 3 distinct peaks.
I hope I summarized my problem correctly.

Answer (score 1):

There a many things that have to work right to get a result here. It is impossible for us to figure out which part of your setup is malfunctioning. If I were you, I'd start debugging by substituting a pulser generating a known signal for your detector, and try to follow the signal through the machinery. You can control the pulse amplitude and see if it changes the peak channel.